# PSRAM use in Ethernet with ESP32

Tags: esp32, ethernet

I am planning to use the LAN8710A PHY with the ESP_WROOM-32 board.

However, I am not sure about the PSRAM requirement for the Ethernet interface on the ESP32. Does the ESP32 Ethernet interface need PSRAM (pseudo-static RAM)?

Will I be able to use the LAN8710A PHY without any problems, even if I don't add any PSRAM?

Comment: the LAN8710A PHY is supported for ESP32. why do you doubt it?

Comment: Why is PSRAM needed? Not all of us are intimately familiar with the LAN8710A

Comment: Depends on the code - the hardware doesn’t require psram but the code might demand more ram.